# How to figure out what is prompting gpg pinentry?

Tags: gpg

Sometimes I get a pinentry popup from gpg. Although I'm currently playing around with some automation so it is not entirely surprising it would be nice to know what exactly is requesting access to the key. There is some info in journalctl, but that mostly only tells me when gpg-agent is called. Is there a way to know for sure what is calling gpg?